# Button press animation in WPF without the ButtonChrome?

Tags: wpf, animation, button

There's a weird interaction going on inside of my WPF application.  I have styled all my buttons so they have a dark blue background with white letters.  They look great, until you click on them and they get the focus.  After that, the literally blink, with the background color gradually fading to a milky blue-ish white to my color choice.  This is distracting to the users and has to go.

We are assuming that the ButtonChrome is responsible for this odd looking animation.  So I want to change the template for my buttons so it uses a rectangle with my background color and a dashed line surrounding the text when the button has the focus.  But I still want to have the button look like it's being depressed into the application when it's clicked.

How do I do this bit of animation efficiently without the ButtonChrome?

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the VisualStateManager and include an animation for the Focussed and/or IsPressed states

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I appreciate the pointer.  But I think I already knew that.  I was looking more for "draw this element with this (these) color(s), then draw that element."  More of the nitty gritty of what to actually draw rather than the generality of using the VisualStateManager.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if you want your button to animate properly, you need a ButtonChrome.  The solution, it turns out, is to create your own ButtonChrome class and use that in your style.  Note that I didn't want to get rid of all of the animations, just the one that occurs when the control is the default button or has focus.

I was able to find the source for the Aero Theme ButtonChrome in another post here on StackOverflow that dealt with a similar problem.  I don't have the URL handy at the moment.  When I find it, I shall update this answer with that URL.

In any event, I removed the offending animations and now my buttons don't have the unwanted effect.